# React frontend communcation without backend

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

can I send a message from one frontend user to another frontend user .These web application frontends are made using react .

Comment: what if i can store user ip and collectively send a web request to all of them .Is there any way to do that

Comment: Look into WebRTC.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can, by using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: No, you can't. You could through WebRTC, but not through WebSockets. Even the link you posted says *"L'API WebSocket [...] permet d'ouvrir un canal de communication bidirectionnelle entre un navigateur (côté client) et un **serveur**."*